# ¿Cómo cambiar el valor del formato currency en devextreme?

Tags: html, angular

Tengo este codigo

...

dxi-column

caption="Importe" dataField="Importe" [format]="{type : 'currency'  ,   currency: 'MXN' , precision: 2 }"

/dxi-column

...

Quiero cambiar el formato, ejemplo ese codigo me muestra esto: "17.700" y quiero "17,700.00"

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso particular yo suelo utilizar esto:

`{{Value|currency:"MXN":"symbol"}}`

En tu código sería:

`{{item.DictamenSolicitudAltaPresentacion.PrecioBase | currency:"MXN":"symbol" }}`

En la documentación oficial de angular viene como utilizar este tipo de pipe de manera mas adecuada :)

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya lo intenté. sin embargo mi problema es que al momento de ver el resultado sale en formato EU Ejemplo: $14,00.00 y lo que quiero es que sea $14.00,00. Primero el punto y despues la coma.